# I have JS form with dynamic link based on date input, I need to output in DD-MM-YYYY format

Tags: javascript, forms, date

I have a booking form where a user selects two dates. The user is then sent to an URL based on the date inputs:

```
<form class="availability-form" id="booking">
    <input type="text" name="arrival" id="arrival" class="awe-calendar from" placeholder="Arrival Date">
    <input type="text" name="departure" id="departure" class="awe-calendar to" placeholder="Departure Date">
    <div class="availability-submit">
        <button type="submit" id="button" class="awe-btn awe-btn-13">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am using the following to navigate to the custom URL:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#booking").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.replace(
                "http://www.example.com/page/" +
                $("#arrival").val() + "/" +
                $("#departure").val()
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code does a great job at sending visitors to the URL with date format MM/DD/YYYY.

However, the booking service I am using requires the date in DD-MM-YYYY. I would change the entire website to that format, but it is not universally recognized.

The easy solution would be to use three different inputs for the day, month, and year, but I was hoping I can keep my pretty looking calendar popup, and convert the format as the user submits the form. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks for the help.

**Edit:**

Here's where I'm at:

```
    var arrive = document.getElementById("arrival").value.split('/');
    var depart = document.getElementById("departure").value.split('/');  $(document).ready(function () {
$("#booking").on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/page/" + arrive[0] + "-" + arrive[1] + "-" + arrive[2] + "/" + depart[0] + "-" + depart[1] + "-" + depart[2]);
});  });
```

The URL I am sent to has only undefined values:

```
http://www.example.com/page/-undefined-undefined/-undefined-undefined
```

I'm not sure why it is not picking up the inputs. I also have no clue why the `arrive[0]` and `depart[0]` do not even show up.

Any additional help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried https://momentjs.com/?

Comment: For humans, DD-MM-YYYY is far more widely recognised (in both numbers and geographic extent) than MM/DD/YYYY. If all you want to do is convert MM/DD/YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY, there are many answers here already for that. Try [*split*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [*join*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), do not be tempted to convert to a Date just for the sake of reordering some characters.

Comment: E.g. `var a = 'MM/DD/YY'.split('/'); console.log(\`${a[1]}-${a[0]}-${a[2]}\`)`. No library, no Date issues, very simple. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Thank you so much for the help. I think I am on the right track with the following: `var a = document.getElementById("arrival").value.split('/'); 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#booking").on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/page/" + a[1]);
    });
  });` I tried it once and it worked perfectly, but then I tried it again, and it didn't work. I am not sure why it is not being reliable.